# Cómo conectar Visual Studio 2013 con MS Access 2016

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ms-access, oledb

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de escritorio con **Visual Studio 2013** y tengo una base de datos con muchísimos datos en **MS Access**. No sé cómo crear una conexión. Cuando trato de crear un *data source* me dice que no tengo instalado el proveedor. No sé que hacer.

Comment: que proveedor estas buscando? con oledb provider no anda?

Comment: porque sigues usando VS 2013 actualiza ya

Answer (score 1):

Intenta instalar [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). Es el driver para hacer conexiones de datos con Access y Excel.

Solo debes tomar en cuenta:

- Si hay una instalación de office, la version que instales del driver debe ser la misma, en cuanto si es 32 bit o 64 bit.
- La version del archivo de Access que estas usando, si es 2003 tienes que usar el driver para 2003 (Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0) o si es 2007 en adelante (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0) la version del link.

Comment: Como las respuestas no deben ser utilizadas para pedir aclaraciones ni sobre la pregunta, hice un pequeño ajuste. Para solicitar aclaraciones se utilizan los comentarios, pero para tener comentar en cualquier parte se require tener 50 puntos de reputación. Sigue participando y es muy probable que los obtengas pronto.